# Why can't I install software through my working Internet connection?

Tags: networking, wireless, apt, software-installation, proxy

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Vostro 1014. While I was installing the OS, my system was connected to a network via the LAN cable. The network required a proxy for connection. Now when I am trying to install LaTeX, VLC, etc., from my home network with different proxy, I am unable to do so. I am getting the following message:

```
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
0% [Connecting to 172.16.1.19 (172.16.1.19)] [Connecting to 172.16.1.19 (172.16.1.19)]
```

P.S. 172.16.1.19 is the proxy address of my office network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the proxy when you're using your home network.

Your office proxy seems to be a local one (as it should be), as it's in a private IPv4 address space (172.16.x.x). As such, you can only connect to it when you're in the same network, i.e. you're connected to your office network.